# How to retrieve a column of data using a dataframe name within a list? R

Tags: r

If this exists somewhere already I apologize but I have not been able to find anything on this. I have only found information on pulling out a column that contains a numerical header.

I am analyzing data from an array, so the titles of my csv's that I am importing are for example (1,1) , (1,2).... etc. I am able to read the file and load it into R as a data frame, but my need after that is to be able to read a single column of data out of it and load it into another dataframe. I import my data using

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv") #import all .csv files 
for (i in 1:length(temp)) { 
     assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))}
```

Then once it is in I need to take out each column and place the data into there respected data frames. The data spread sheet looks like this

```
#(1 1).csv
#     10nA   100nA    1uA
#  1  1562    562     256
#  2  1675    623     275  
#  3  1608    594     269
```

How am I able to access the file once it is loaded using the filenames located in temp? That way it can be put in a loop for my 500+ files.

Ex:

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)){     #creating the tables for 10,100,1000nA
    `10nA` <- as.data.frame(temp[i][, "X10nA"])}

tennA <- as.data.frame(temp[i]$X10nA)     
# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
tennA <- as.data.frame(temp[i][, "X10nA"])
# Error in temp[i][, "X10nA"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Where temp is:

```
temp  chr [1:30]  "(1 1).csv" "(1,2).csv" ... etc
```

Comment: try \`(1 1).csv\`

Comment: Yes that worked great and now I am trying to be able to use a loop to read through the file names.

Comment: You want `get()`. Try `get(temp[1])$10nA`.